# Strange results from my FM synthesis algorithm

Tags: audio

It seems that I haven't studied enough about FM Synthesis.
My current algorithm looks like this:

```
modulator = sin( 2 * pi * fm_freq * i/sample_rate )
carrier = sin( 2 * pi * ( freq + modulator ) * i/sample_rate )
```

Instead of generating one stable waveform, it generates a sound warping from a pure sine wave to something awfully distorted. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be more like this:

```
modulator = A_mod * sin(2 * pi * fm_freq * i / sample_rate)

carrier = sin (2 * pi * (freq * (1 + modulator)) * i / sample_rate)
```

The two main changes are:

- the modulation signal needs a scale factor (`A_mod`) which determines the amplitude of the FM - typically `A_mod << 1`
- the carrier frequency needs to be multiplied by `(1 + modulator)` rather than just `modulator`, since it needs to be centered about `freq` with a deviation of `+/- A_mod * freq` (in your version the centre frequency is zero and your instantaneous frequency is varying between `+/- freq` !).

Comment: +1  for reminding the OP to include `A_mod << 1` in `modulator`.  I assume the OP has already ensured that `fm_freq << freq` because if not, one can get quite unexpected results.

Comment: What does the `<<`  imply here?

Comment: `<<` is the mathematical sense of “very much less than”.

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing is actually phase modulation rather than frequency modulation. You mustn't multiply the modulator with the sample index then, though: try

```
carrier = sin( 2 * pi * ( freq*i/sample_rate + modulator ) )
```

An actual frequency modulation is not quite as simple, it would be rather something like

```
phi += 2 * pi * (freq + modulator)/sample_rate
carrier = sin(phi)
```